# Loop to increase value on Parameter of Model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, loop, parameters

I'm working on the ArcGIS Model Builder to develop a model that makes a Raster Calculation using a Value Parameter and analyzes the maximum pixel value of the result, comparing to a Reference Value.

If the maximum pixel value is lower then the reference value, I need to increase "1" at the Variant Parameter and do the Raster Calculation again, and after to do it many times, until the maximum pixel value is higher or equal to the Reference Value. I'll continue to other calculations that I'm not working on yet.

That is a picture of the model, and I need to connect the "lower" box to the "Variant".

[image: Model Picture]

Comment: Calculate Value might do what you want http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000v8000000